# Got a raspberry pi 3b+ 3v3 pin shorted. What can i do?

Tags: gpio, boot, pi-3b+

I've bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model b+, to try as a simple computer

Put it on the case, tried for some time, but it did not hit the performance i was expecting, so droped this idea.
I kept it save, always in the case, cause some day i would play with it. Didn't touch for almost a year

Now i was trying to install retropie in it, so could play on the TV, without need to take my laptop there.
But could't boot at all, *pwr* light on, no *act*, no video (a black [actually a blue '-'] screen)
Found on [raspberry pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58151) about some PI "suddenly has stopped booting, after shorting the 3V3 to GND". So i got a multimeter, tested mine PI turned off, and it really seems to have the 3v3's shorted to the GDN's pins
I see no way it could happened, since have not even played with it yet.

So now, as it seems that the PI is dead, since there is not way a can replace the MxL7704 chip (what some places say could fix it), what can i do?
Considering that here raspberry PI is not really cheap, and i've spent 250 "bucks" on it, i would like a solution to not lose that piece.

Comment: When powered up 3V3 should be available at pin 1.  If you don't measure 3V3 between pin 1 (3V3) and pin 6 (ground) when the Pi is powered then the Pi is bust.  There is no economical repair.

Comment: One of the best ways to kill a Pi is to poke at the 3.3V pin with a multimeter lead - it only takes milliseconds.

Comment: You need to measure the voltage between pin#1 and the outside case of the USB. Then measure pin#2 and the outside of the USB. The first reading should be 3.3V the second should be 5V. If the 3.3V supply is missing then you have destroyed the PMIC and you need a new Raspberry Pi. One meter probe is safer than poking header pins with two probes.

Comment: I did test it powered up too, 3v3 to GDN gets nothing, while 5v is fine. The same to xv and outside of USB (i just did)
Recording that i've never played with the pins before (didn't even had a multimeter), i just did if **after** seeing it on the forum, to test if mine was broken

So that's it? Nothing to do? 250 directly to trash, without even a single minute of playing?